# How to make a copy of a java Scanner?

Tags: java, clone, java.util.scanner

I am reading a file in java using Scanner. In the middle of reading I want to save special paragraph in an array while reading the file so I need to use extra scanner to do it. I can't use one scanner since two scanner process the file differently (have different responsibility). In below code how can I make a copy of scan??

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("test.txt");
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
          String token = scan.next();   
          if(token.compare("START")==0)
          {
              Scanner temp = scan; //How can I make a copy of scan? 
              //scan.clone() does not work
              String curVal =temp.next();
              while(curVal.compare("END") != 0)
              {
                   ...
                   curVal =temp.next() //scan should not go to the next value
              }
          }   
      }

      Example:

      1H2i345
      Thi67s
      START
      I am5678 special bla790b bla...
      END
      We are continuing.

      output:
      String special_para ="I am5678 special bla790b bla..."
      The scan should remove all the numbers (it is just an example what scan does is much more complicated)
```

Comment: You're almost certainly going at this wrong. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Dont use `if(token == "START")` for string comparison, will give you unexpected result, instead use `if("START".equals(token))`

Comment: I have updated the question. Why people asking to close it??

Comment: You cannot read and write to the same file, it gets locked. You should store the data inside a variable instead and write it after the reading is done.

Comment: This is still pretty unclear.  Are you saying you want to save a portion of your test.txt file?

Comment: No both of them are reading I dont want to write to the file

Comment: try using temp=scan.clone(); that should work.

Comment: There is no clone for scanner that is my problem

Comment: You already have the file open, why do you want to open it again?

Comment: I have updated please check it

Comment: What's wrong with having a flag that says "I'm inside the `START` block, perform different functionality until I hit the `END`" and just using the same Scanner?

Comment: Show us an example of your text file and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Then how should I go back to the start? Assuming we should process the whole file and while we are saving START...END we cant do that process

Comment: Can you describe the process that should happen before you get to the `START/END` block? Then describe the process that should happen inside the block? I think I'm having a hard time understanding why you need to go back to the start of the file.

Comment: sorry about confusion done

Answer (score 1):

Objects have a clone method that can be used to copy the object.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Java_method)

What are you trying to accomplish by copying it, though? There may be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, I know about cloning and because of that I added the ":clone" tag to this question. But I could not clone the scanner!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a second Scanner. You just need to add a flag and a new condition. (Unless I'm misunderstanding, and you **do** need to go back to the start of the file.)

```
bool insideStartBlock = false;
Scanner scan = new Scanner("test.txt");
while(scan.hasNext())
{
    String token = scan.next();   
    if("START".equals(token))
    {
        insideStartBlock = true;
    }
    else if ("END".equals(token)
    {
        insideStartBlock = false;
    }
    else if (insideStartBlock)
    {
        ...
        <do work based on token>
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it needs lot of modification but ofcourse it works. I dont know why clone does not work!